# Camera not opening after granting the permission in surface view

Tags: android, camera

I am making a custom camera application. Which requires surface view and opens the camera inside the surface view. 
But when running the same application on marshmallow I am using `Runtime permission` to grant permission for camera. After I allow the dialog disappears but black screen shows up and camera doesn't get open. 
I have tried also by calling the activity again after allowing but its not working.

THANX in advance.

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (preview) {
        camera.stopFaceDetection();
        camera.stopPreview();
        preview = false;
    }

    if (camera != null) {
        preview = true;
        // Parameters
        Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        List<Camera.Size> sizeList = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        bestSize = sizeList.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < sizeList.size(); i++) {
            if ((sizeList.get(i).width * sizeList.get(i).height) >
                    (bestSize.width * bestSize.height)) {
                bestSize = sizeList.get(i);
            }
        }
        parameters.setPictureSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
        camera.startFaceDetection();
        camera.setFaceDetectionListener(faceDetectionListener);
    }
}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    customsurfaceview();
}
public void customsurfaceview() {

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Log.e("PLAYGROUND", "Permission is not granted, requesting");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 123);
    }
    Log.e("Entered Surace Created", "----------------");
}
public void SetPreview_onSurface() {
    if (camera == null)
        return;


    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("printStackTrace", "--" + e.getMessage());

    }
    camera_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    camera_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (capture_chek == 0) {
                camera.cancelAutoFocus();
                camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, pictureCallback);
                capture_chek = 1;
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
        preview = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: show some code you tried yet

Comment: i am not able to put my code in here. as it is giving me indent error.

Comment: all i can say is that after i run the application i am prompted to runtime permissions. it shows the layout but after i close the the application and start it again it works. any idea how to create surface again after allowing the permission.

Comment: Please post your full code@Vijay,otherwise we are unable to debug your problem.

Comment: is there any way to attach word file here.??

Comment: see can you find the code here http://pastebin.com/SvhBabXz

Comment: are you able to see the code??

Comment: Edit your question and Copy-paste your code here Activity class code in which you are declaring Run time permissions. Because without viewing your code we aren't able to understand where you are doing wrong

Comment: i have uploaded my code please have a look at it.

Comment: @Vijay were you able to resolve this?

Comment: use this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47573182/surface-view-does-not-show-camera-after-i-gave-permission/60409686#60409686

Answer (score 3):

This question might be too old, but to help other people who'll encounter the same problem as I did. My fix was...

In OnCreate() I removed setContentView(R.layout...) then I will only call initializeUiAndCamera() in OnCreate() and in onRequestPermissionsResult() if the permissions are granted.

Inside initializeUiAndCamera() here I called setContentView(R.layout...) and inflated all the views I needed.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), REQUEST_CAMERA)
    else
        initializeUiAndCamera()
}

private fun initializeUiAndCamera() {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr_scanner)

    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView)

    //...
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_CAMERA -> {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
                initializeUiAndCamera()
            else 
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Camera Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }
    }
}
```

TLDR; Only inflate your views when the permissions are granted.

Comment: What about to add Finish(); after "Camera permission denied"?

Comment: @WarrenCedro i solved the problem by ripping the view from its parent and putting it right back, i couldnt avoid initializeCameraView , but i did a removeCameraView, putCameraViewBack instead

Comment: @SteveRogers you could also do that.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem, please see my example

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    // grant permission
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
        return;
    }

    // ***HERE*** is my error: if camera permission not granted all of below 
    // code will never call

    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    // set preview
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
    }

    //btn to close the application
    ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    imgClose.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

then i create a function `initial()` to bound all init code when permission granted call init again

```
public class CameraActivity extends MediaPickerBaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA = 77;
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraView mCameraView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        setCancelFlag();

        // grant permission
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA);
            return;
        }
        initial();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSION_CAMERA) {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initial();
            } else {
                // TODO: 5/8/17 show permission denied
                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * set cancel state from bundle (default: true)
     *
     * @see #isCancelIntermediate
     * @see #flagCancelIntermediate
     */
    private void setCancelFlag() {
        isCancelIntermediate = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(flagCancelIntermediate, true);
    }

    /**
     * init view and camera
     */
    private void initial() {
        try {
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // set preview
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(this, mCamera);//create a SurfaceView to show camera data
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);//add the SurfaceView to the layout
        }

        //btn to close the application
        ImageButton imgClose = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
        imgClose.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.imgClose)
            cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void cancel() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void sendResult() {

    }
}
```

hope this will helpful.